# Error when calling Excel macro from C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to call a macro from an Excel file using `C# 4.5`. My Excel version is 2010.

When I try to call the macro, I get the following error:

```
Cannot run the macro 'MacroName'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I have googled a lot for this, but nothing really seems to work.

I have opened up macro security, as the following screen shot shows:

[image: Macro Security]

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Excel.Application book = null;
Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
Excel.Workbook macroWorkbook = null;
Excel.Workbook destinationWorkbook = null;

try
{
    book = new Excel.Application();

    workbooks = book.Workbooks;
    macroWorkbook = workbooks.Open(@"D:\Work\Macros.xls");
    destinationWorkbook = workbooks.Open(@"D:\Work\Destination.xlsx");

    book.Run("MacroName");

    macroWorkbook.Close(false);
    destinationWorkbook.Close(true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex; // the finally will be executed before this is thrown
}
finally
{
    book.Quit();

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(macroWorkbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(destinationWorkbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);

    macroWorkbook = null;
    destinationWorkbook = null;
    workbooks = null;
    book = null;
}
```

The actual macro is stored in `Macros.xls` and will run on the `Destination.xslx`. When I run this macro in `Excel` itself, there is no problem.

Comment: You need to tell Excel which workbook the macro is in.  See Help for Application.Run

Comment: @TimWilliams: Sorry. Just saw your comment. Deleted my post.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - you should leave your post!  I was too lazy to post an answer....

Comment: @TimWilliams: But now you can... Lazy? It's just one line :p

Comment: ...crappy ipad keyboard...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
book.Run ("'Macros.xls'!MacroName");
```