# Add a macro in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, vba

i have the following macro

```
Sub test()
    Dim xsheet As Worksheet
    For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        xsheet.Select
        With xsheet.UsedRange
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Next xsheet      
End Sub
```

Is there a way to add it to excel file and to execute it using c# ?

Any help would be the most appreciated .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508569/error-when-calling-excel-macro-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Here is the code I use that works for Excel using the **.Net reference:** Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel v14 (not the ActiveX COM Reference):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunVBATest();
}

public static void RunVBATest()
{
    Application oExcel = new Application();
    oExcel.Visible = true;
    Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
    _Workbook oBook = oBooks.Open("C:\\temp\\Book1.xlsm");

    // Run the macro.
    RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "TestMsg" });
    //Run a macro with parameters        
    //RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "ShowMsg", "Hello from C# Client", "Demo to run Excel macros from C#" });

    // Quit Excel and clean up
    oBook.Saved = true;
    oBook.Close(false);
    oExcel.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
}

private static void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
    oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, oApp, oRunArgs);

}
}
}
}
```

2) make sure you put the Macro code in a Module (a Global BAS file)..

```
Public Sub TestMsg()

MsgBox ("Hello Stackoverflow")

End Sub
```

3) make sure you enable Macro Security and Trust access to the VBA Project object model:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution by [Siddharth Rout](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/siddharth%20rout/) extracted from this [MSDN issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e33b8e5-c9fd-42a1-8d67-3d61d2cedc1c/how-to-call-excel-macros-programmatically-in-c?forum=exceldev)

This should work :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //~~> Define your Excel Objects
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

            //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\Users\\Siddharth Rout\\Desktop\\book1.xlsm");

            //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("test");

            //~~> Clean-up: Close the workbook
            xlWorkBook.Close(false);

            //~~> Quit the Excel Application
            xlApp.Quit();

            //~~> Clean Up
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        }

        //~~> Release the objects
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your macro has arguments, lets say :

```
Sub ShowMsg(msg As String, title As String)
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, title
End Sub
```

You have to change `xlApp.Run("test");` to `xlApp.Run("ShowMsg", "Hello from C# Client", "Demo to run Excel macros from C#");`

Comment: Ha Ha.. I had forgotten about that post :D

Comment: Well, since you're here, you should answer and get the bounty :-p

Comment: Nah. It is all yours :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout How can I insert macro in the excel file ?